# Can a mining proxy be installed on an Antminer S1?

Tags: asic, proxy

I recently acquired an Antminer S1 and I also own a Block Erupter Cube. The Block Erupter Cube works with the old Getwork protocol so the best way to use it is to run a mining proxy on a PC in the local network. However, I would prefer to not need the PC and since I notice the Antminer S1 has some storage space available I wonder if it would be possible to SSH into it and install a mining proxy in it so that the Block Erupter Cube get its work through the Antminer rather than through the PC?

Comment: One possible solution is to use a Rasp Pi to run a proxy for both the cube and S1 (you need separate proxies for each). Simply setup the Pi to run two proxies listening on different ports and point the miners at each. The reason 2 proxies are needed (at least for me) is that the Cubes wont function with the "-nm" (no midstate) command while the S1's need it, and the S1s wont function well with "-rt" (real-target) command, but the cubes require it. This is how I control several cubes/S1s with two proxies and it works quite well. BFGMiner can control Cubes well with it's proxy (but not S1s).

Comment: Well, I'd only be running the proxy for the Cube since I have the S1 connecting directly to the pool that I use rather than through the mining proxy. So any Raspberry Pi will do? I've not done much research on them but that sets me on the path what I want so I'll look into it.

Comment: I would highly recommend using MinePeon for your Pi and use BFGMiner as the proxy. Just use the command "--http-port 8335" or whatever port you like (8332 can cause problems if your running the QT client). As far as getting a proxy on the S1 control board, I highly doubt it would be able to handle the extra load from a proxy (already is bogged down from it's own CGMiner instance), and would be hard fitting on the unit, as it only has 4.2MB of free space with the latest image, and the commonly used "Slush's" proxy is 5.16MB (found here: http://mining.bitcoin.cz/mining-proxy-howto).

Answer (score -1):

I'd say `Antminer` does not have any operating system inside.. so if I'm not wrong, no, you can't.

Comment: It runs openWRT which is a Linux distribution, but I don't know how limited it is which is why I asked the question. I"m not very familiar with it.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong then :) Have you tried looking at the repositories of `openwrt`? [Here](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/bitcoinmining) a miner is installed on `openwrt` so i'd say it would be possible to install a mining proxy, maybe they already have one on their repos..